# Algorithm for converting an arbitrarily long String representing a decimal number into a String representing a hexadecimal number

Tags: c, bignum, base-conversion

I am currently working on a program in C17, which receives a string from the command line, lets call it st_in. I know that st_in will only contain chars in range [0x30, 0x39], thus represent a decimal number of arbitrary size. I want to convert this string into a string st_out which does represent the same value in hexadecimal, eg. f("123") would yield "7B". The caveat comes from the fact that st_in and st_out can be really big. So I need to convert them digitwise. Is there a standard way of doing it?

All my previous attempts at solving the problem lead me to very complex "ripple-back" ideas, which I can barely grasp conceptually, let alone write down in good ol' C. I also don't really know how to allocate the memory correctly (if n = strlen(st_in) I have found that the maximum number of digits would be
ceil(n * log_2(10). But then I need to free just "some" of the memory if the string is shorter.

Comment: I would think the most straight-forward way would be the same as you would do with pen-and-paper - by repeated division by 16. You will have to implement this division first of course...

Comment: And you thought you would never use grade school math and long division again.

Comment: Convert the `st_in` input to an array of `uint_32`, char-by-char. Just multiply array by `10`, add char from `st_in` while avoid overflows and doing `realloc` management. Once all input has been dealt with, converting an array of `uint_32`s to an hex string should be easy. Use `uint_64` for the multiplication by `10` and to catch overflows.

Comment: For the memory allocation, simply allocate the same amount of space as for the decimal value — the hex representation will not be longer.  If you're really worried about over-allocation at the end, use `strdup()` or an equivalent to allocate the space actually used.  Don't let the memory allocation issue hold up progress on the main task — converting decimal to hexadecimal.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Given the computer effectively provides base-16 arithmetic, you would want to work in that base, focusing on multiplying by 10 rather than dividing by 16. Start with the first decimal digit. Multiply by 10 and add the next digit. Repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm is:

- Calculate a maximum length that might be needed for the output, including space for terminating null character.
- Initialize *last* to point to the end of that space.
- Initialize *first* to point one beyond *last*, indicating the output string is currently empty. (If *first* and *last* pointed to the same place, there would be one digit there. When *first* points beyond *last*, it means there are no digits yet.)
- While there is another input digit to process:

  - Convert the input digit from a decimal character to an integer in 0-9.
  - Using algorithm below, multiply the output string by ten and add the new input digit.
- Move the output string in positions *first* to *last* to the beginning of the allocated space (because it grew at the end and might not have reached the front, depending on how whether the maximum length was calculated exactly or not).
- Convert the output string from integers in 0-15 to hexadecimal characters.
- Write a null character to mark the end of the string.
- If desired, and the output length was not initially calculated exactly, reallocate the space to just fit.

To multiply the output string by ten and add the new input digit:

- Initialize *carry* to the current input digit, as an integer in 0-9.
- For each position *p* from *last* down to to *first*, inclusive:

  - Set *carry* to be 10 times the digit in position *p* plus *carry*. (*carry* is temporarily a larger amount than will be carried.)
  - Find the low hexadecimal digit of *carry* by taking the remainder modulo 16. Store that in position *p*.
  - Find the high hexadecimal digit of *carry* by dividing it by 16, with truncation.
- If *carry* is not zero, the output has grown left one digit. Decrement *first* by one and store *carry* at the new position.

Comment: This is a great answer! I had some kind of barrier in my head when approaching the problem at first, but this not only answers the question, but also provides some really good insight in how someone might do this! I ended up not using the string conversion, but converting a BIG number to an array of 32 bit integers. But the method is splended!